# The sum of a normal and nilpotent matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are such that $A$ is normal, $B$ is nilpotent, and $A + B = I$.  Prove that $A=I$.

Answer (score 2):

$B$ is normal, since
$$BB^\dagger=(I-A)(I-A)^\dagger=I-A-A^\dagger-AA^\dagger$$
$$B^\dagger B=(I-A)^\dagger(I-A)=I-A^\dagger-A-A^\dagger A$$
and $A$ is normal, so by [$A$ is normal and nilpotent, show $A=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68762/a-is-normal-and-nilpotent-show-a-0?rq=1), $B=0$ and $A=I$.