# Linear complex extension of a representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Consider the following matrices,
$$H=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{matrix}\right) 
\qquad X=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{matrix}\right)
\qquad Y=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Let $\rho:\mathfrak{su}(2)\rightarrow \text{End}(V)$ be a lie algebra homomorphism such that $\rho(X)^*=-\rho(X)$. Does this imply that $\rho(Y)^*=-\rho(Y)$?

I have been trying to use the commutation relations of $H,X,Y$ and the fact that $\rho$ is a lie algebra homomorphism to show this but I can't see to do it.

Am I overlooking something obvious here?

Comment: Those matrices are not in $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. I assume you mean $\rho: \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb C} \rightarrow End_{\mathbb C} (V)$ (with $V$ a finite-dim. complex vector space)?

Comment: Also, could you write down a non-trivial (but easy) example of such a representation where $\rho(X)^\ast =-\rho(X)$?

Comment: Yes you are coorect I should have said $\rho: \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb C} \rightarrow End_{\mathbb C}(V)$. If I understand correctly, to write donw a representation it is enough to write down what it does to the basis elements $H,X,Y$? I thought sending $H,X,Y$ to the pauli matrices might work but that doesn't respect the bracket. Now I am trying to map into $\mathbb{R}^3$ and use the cross product as the lie algebra bracket? Is this along the right line or could you hint at an easy example?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg the representation $\rho: \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb C}\rightarrow  \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb C}$ given by $\rho(A)=iA$ seems to work. This certainly gives $\rho(Y)^*=-\rho(Y)$

Comment: But is this true for all representations ?

Comment: That's not a representation, since $[iX, iY] \neq i[X,Y]$. In general, multiplication with a constant $c \neq 0,1$ is not a Lie algebra homomorphism unless the Lie algebra is abelian.

Comment: By the way, I assumed above and in my answer that $^\ast$ means hermitian transpose. But besides the proposed $\rho$ not being a representation, also $\pmatrix{0&i\\0&0}^\ast =\pmatrix{0&0\\-i&0} \neq \pmatrix{0&-i\\0&0}$. Maybe you just meant complex conjugate with $^\ast$? The answer to that might be less trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is true, but for a striking reason: If $\rho: \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb C} (\simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)) \rightarrow End_{\mathbb C}(V)$ is a (finite dimensional, complex) Lie algebra representation with $\rho(X)^\ast =-\rho(X)$, then $\rho$ is the trivial representation $\rho =0$.

Namely, it is well-known or easily proven that $\rho(X)$ must be nilpotent. But:

**Lemma**: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb C$-vector space with hermitian inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$, and let $A \in End_{\mathbb C}(V)$ be nilpotent. Then $A^\ast =-A \Rightarrow A=0$.

**Proof**: Assume $A \neq 0$, then there is $0 \neq v_1 \in V$ with $v_0 := Av_1 \neq 0$ and $Av_0 =0$. So $$ 0 = \langle 0, v_1 \rangle =\langle Av_0, v_1 \rangle = \langle v_0, A^\ast v_1\rangle = \langle v_0, -Av_1 \rangle = -\langle v_0, v_0 \rangle \neq 0,$$
contradiction. (For different proofs and generalisations, compare e.g. [$A$ is normal and nilpotent, show $A=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68762/96384).)

Now from $\rho(X)=0$ it follows easily (if one does not know it from the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$) that $\rho(H)$, and a fortiori $\rho(Y)$, are $=0$.