# If $\mathbf{A}$ is real symmetric, prove $\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{0}$ implies $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

For all $\mathbf{x}$, we see that $\mathbf{A}^n\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. Therefore we can construct a linearly independent basis of eigenvectors (each with eigenvalue $0$). Following from this, the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$ must also form a basis, with eigenvalues $0^{1/n}=0$. Since a square matrix is diagonalizable iff there is a basis of its eigenvectors, there exists a frame in where $\mathbf{A} = \mathrm{diag}(0,\cdots,0) = \mathbf{0}$. However $\mathbf{0}\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{0}$ for all matrices $\mathbf{M}$ so therefore $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0}$ in any frame.

Is this proof complete? Where have I used the fact that $\boldsymbol{A}$ is real symmetric? The question actually asks you to consider the quadratic form $Q = \mathbf{x^T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ but how does this help? Are there any other proofs?

Comment: You used that $\mathbf A$ is symmetric in the first argument ("therefore we can..."), this is the spectral theorem.

Comment: @nicomezi but does that not follow from the fact that $\mathbf{A}^n\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ for any vector $\mathbf{x}$ - which doesn't make a reference to $\mathbf{A}$ being symmetric?

Comment: No, because in general matrices are not diagonalizable. Basically your proof is saying: any nilpotent matrix which is diagonalizable is zero, and any real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, therefore any real symmetric nilpotent matrix is zero.

Comment: You never explained why the eigenvectors of $A^n$ are the same of those of $A$

Comment: A **real entries** symmetric matrix is always diagonalizable...

Comment: The statement as it stands is false. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&i\\ i&-1}$ for instance. It is true over $\mathbb R$, however, and we can actually prove a [stronger statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68762).

Comment: I should also point out that as such, the statement is just false, you need to assume that the matrix has real coefficients. You don't even have to work with weird fields, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} i & 1 \\ 1 & -i \end{pmatrix}$  is already a counter-example over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Seems like everyone had the same idea at the same time.

Comment: @user1551 I have edited the question - thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: As for considering the associated quadratic form, I have no idea what the person who wrote the exercise was thinking about, and I suspect this is a mistake, because the matrix representation of bilinear forms has very little to do with matrix products, and I really don't see how you're going to deduce anything from the fact that $A$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 2):

By induction. Let $n>1$ then for any $x, y \in V$ $$0 = \langle A^n x, y \rangle = \langle A^{n-1} x, A y \rangle.$$ This shows that $A^{n-1}V$ is orthogonal to $A V$ and in particular, since $A^{n-1}V \subseteq AV$, $A^{n-1}V$ is orthogonal to itself. Therefore $A^{n-1} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\text{tr}(A^TA)=0$ implies $A=0$. Since $A$ is symmetric, then it
follows from $A^2=0$ that $A=0$.

Moreover, if $A$ is symmetric and $A^n=0$, there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2^k\ge n$ and then $A^{2^k}=A^{n}A^{2^k-n}=0$. By induction we obtain
$$A^{2^k}=0\Longrightarrow A^{2^{k-1}}=0\Longrightarrow\cdots\Longrightarrow A=0.$$